# Can I replace a 32 A switch with a 32 A MCB?

Tags: wiring, electrical, circuit-breaker, automatic-circuit-breaker

A switch for a water heater in my apartment is broken (image attached).
It is an "Anchor Roma 32 Amp 1-Way Switch with indicator".

Can I replace it with [this](https://www.amazon.in/Anchor-Panasonic-98006-Polycarbonate-Ampere/dp/B00V4VENFC/ref=olp_product_details?ie=UTF8&me=) or [this](https://www.amazon.in/Havells-DHMGCSNF032-MCB-SPN-Curve/dp/B07BH4BP97/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=mcb%2032&qid=1590909643&refinements=p_85%3A10440599031&rnid=10440598031&rps=1&sr=8-5) switch?

Would the installation be similar or the same?

*Background:*

I am a software engineer; I am not an electrical engineer but I have replaced switches 8-10 times in the past. However I have always purchased the exact same switch.

Should I be paying attention to anything other than the Amperes?

I am in a highly effected (by [covid19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic)) red quarantine zone in Mumbai, India and the switch I am replacing is unavailable. I am also unable to get an electrician because my block has been cordoned off.

[image: The broken switch]

Comment: I am going to say no, circuit breakers are rated for a much lower number of switch cycles than a normal wall switch, so while I may serve the same function, it will fail sooner than the wall switch,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't fit in the box. This means it will be difficult to operate, and will leave parts exposed that should not be.

The 'D. P.' likely means that it is a double pole switch - you should replace it with a double pole switch.

It looks like you can buy an [exact replacement](https://www.amazon.in/ANCHOR-ROMA-Double-Switch-White/dp/B07HNZWVJQ) from the same place for similar cost. You should do this instead.

Comment: Thank you. I actually am not able to get that one delivered to my post code. I suspected it would not fit but I thought I'd live with it. Anyway, thank you very much.